# Use and copy artifacts within one job in multiple subjobs/nodes - Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, artifacts

Hello,
We're using one job (B) which calls another job (C) 3-times with different parameters within one job (B). Every job-C run is used for different slaves/nodes, with different parameters.
Job B is using some artifacts from job A and all the sub-jobs (C) should even uses these artifacts. Unfortunately only the first triggered sub-job (Job C #1) becomes the artifacts provided within his local workspace folder. For the other Job-C runs (#2 and #3) the artifacts will not be copied.

Schema:

```
Job A (creates the artifacts)
-->Job B (uses artifacts from A and triggers Job C, three times)
   --> Job C #1 --> use artifacts for node1
   --> Job C #2 --> should also use the artifacts on node2 (didnt work)
   --> Job C #2 --> should also use the artifacts on node3 (didnt work)
```

One solution could be configure a group for all job-c nodes and to use "execute on all nodes in label" in the trigger. But we need to call Job-C with different parameters.

Thanks Steffen

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution with the [Build Flow plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Flow+Plugin), the [NodeLabel parameter plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/NodeLabel+Parameter+Plugin) and the [Copy Artifact plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin).

With this solution, no need of the job B.

The job A creates the artifacts, no need to update this job.

On the job C, please this kind of parameter (using the second plugin):

[image]

Please active this option for your job C:

[image]

Add a build step to copy the artefact from the job A:

[image]

Next, create a new build flow job with this flow:

```
build("Bruno job A")
parallel (
  { build("Bruno job C", NODE_NAME: "jenkins-centos-slave-01") },
  { build("Bruno job C", NODE_NAME: "jenkins-centos-slave-02") },
  { build("Bruno job C", NODE_NAME: "jenkins-centos-slave-03") }
)
```

The parallel block will launch 3 times the job C on 3 different slaves.

[image]

We can check that the 3 jobs C have been executed on the relevant nodes:

[image]

[image]

[image]

And they all get the artefact from the job A :)

Comment: Hi Bruno, thanks for the quick reply. I'll try it and come back to you

Comment: @Steffen Did you find some time to test my solution? :)